# merged map flickers on Rviz

Tags: navigation, mapping, rviz, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS Melodic, though I'm using the package [multirobot_map_merge](http://wiki.ros.org/multirobot_map_merge) which was developed for Kinetic and Lunar. Works fine if configured, the issue is that on Rviz the resulting map is constantly flickering. You can see what I mean in this video:

[image: flickering map]

What I'm highlighting is the map that is merged in the global `/map` topic. I assume that the two maps `robot1/map` and `robot2/map`, coming from their respective `gmapping` nodes, are "updating" themselves on the `/map` topic rather than being correctely merged. This happens no matter how much I let the robots explore the map. In fact, the more the two maps grow, the more the flickering.

Running `rosrun map_server map_saver` does save the map, but just the portion that is being currently highlighted on Rviz.

I hope it's not a problem of versions: I have other packages that have been distributed for previous releases of ROS but work fine, I don't think that's the case

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337886/merged-map-flickers-on-rviz/) by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-11-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-18**:
To check (from [multirobot_map_merge](http://wiki.ros.org/multirobot_map_merge)):

> First all robots must publish map under `<robot_namespace>/map`, [..]

Is this the case in your setup?

**Comment by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on 2019-11-18**:
Yes, they do by using each a gmapping node. These submaps are the ones that we see "flicker"

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-18**:
Just to be extra clear: so namespaces are being used? It's not that each robot is publishing to`/map` directly? Can you verify?

**Comment by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on 2019-11-18**:
Yes, I have verified. `/map` topic is published only by `robot1/map_merge` and `robot2/map_merge` nodes, but this is the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I understand the wiki page correctly, there should only be a single instance of `map_merge`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on 2019-11-18**:
That's what I think aswell, but the init_pos-es of the robots are required, I can't pass them all at once. That made me think that multiple instances were required

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-18**:
`<robot_namespace>/map_merge` is a namespace. The `map_merge` there is not a node. It's just the namespace the `map_merge` node reads the parameters related to `<robot_namespace>` from.

**Comment by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on 2019-11-18**:
I am sorry, but I didn't understand what you mean. If there are multiple different namespaces (`robot1`, `robot2`, `robotN`) how can `map_merge` get all the parameters it needs from all of them? Eg the `init_pos`es, the current namespace and so on

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-18**:
From the wiki page:

> `multirobot_map_merge` finds robot maps dynamically and new robots can be added to system at any time. To make this dynamic behaviour possible there are some constrains placed on robots. First all robots must publish map under `<robot_namespace>/map`, where topic name (`map`) is configurable, but must be same for all robots. For each robot `<robot_namespace>` will be of cause different.

The node knows how to "scan" for new robots, provided they've properly namespaced their topics and parameters.

**Comment by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on 2019-11-19**:
At first, it didn't work, so I thought it was because multiple instances were necessary. But turns out that I needed an extra "world" frame that I didn't have, adding it without transforms was sufficient.